# Wordpress. Кнопка на сайте не перенаправляет на страницу

Tags: wordpress

На сайте есть три боковые кнопки, каждая из них перенаправляет на свою страницу. Две из трех перенаправляют на свои страницы, а одна ничего не делает, только обновляет страницу. Настроены они все одинаково, страницы созданы тоже без различий в настройке. Кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Сайт http://tek-galaktika.ru кнопки, о которых идет речь, находятся слева в столбик.

Comment: Постоянно сталкиваюсь с тем, что если у ссылки пустой href то она никуда не перенаправляет

Comment: Так href задает адрес документа, на который следует перейти. Насколько я знаю. Если он пустой, то куда ему переходить ))

Comment: Вот именно, что настройки у всех были идентичны, но именно эта кнопка никак не настаивается, я видел, что поле href пустует, но как исправить понять не могу

Comment: @KakNaZlo ну можно добавить href например

Comment: настройки слетают при обновлении страницы, отключал плагины поочередно, думал в них причина, ничего не меняется

Comment: А как она настраивается?

Comment: через админку WP, две другие настроены аналогично и нормально работают, html страницы пока найти немогу

Comment: Обратитесь на фриланс. С таким описанием проблемы никто Вам тут не поможет

Comment: что не так с описанием?

Answer (score 0):

> а одна ничего не делает, только обновляет страницу. Настроены они все
>   одинаково, страницы созданы тоже без различий в настройке

Это не так. В первой не прописана ссылка. `href`  пустой.

```
<a class="btn_online webim_button" href="" rel="webim" style="width: 261px; position: fixed; top: 45%; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 9999; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; border: none; outline: none;"> <img src="http://tek-galaktika.ru/wp-content/themes/translogic-child/img/online2.png" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; border: 0px;"></a>
```

ЗЫ. А остальные и на др страница не работают.

Comment: На других они просто перекрываются другим слоем

Comment: @РашенБеар я видел :)